# Rename MS Word 2010 backstage tab

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, ribbon

I want to rename MS Word 2010 backstage tab from "file" to another name from dotm file.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That's built-in - you can't rename it.

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2007 (I guess it is the same in 2010) you should be able to change the label of the tab by adapting the customUI.xml.

```
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">    
      <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
      <tabs>  
        <tab idMso="TabHome" label="FuBar"/>
...
```

But I never try so... all I did in a project was setting them invisible...

Comment: I am talking about backstage element which exists only in 2010

Comment: Backstage works basically the same as the Ribbon Definition in 2010.

Comment: In fact, you specify both in the CUSTOMUI xml. I'm not sure if the "startfromscratch" option works with Backstage, but it'd be worth a try.